# With a Mac Mini, can I use a HDMI - DVI and DVI - VGA adapter for a CRT monitor?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, mac-mini, adapter

I need this information because the two threads below didn't really clarify.

- [Mac Mini HDMI-to-DVI to VGA-to-Monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/199141/mac-mini-hdmi-to-dvi-to-vga-to-monitor)
- [Macbook Mini-DVI to VGA Output Broken - Cause?](https://superuser.com/questions/11183/macbook-mini-dvi-to-vga-output-broken-cause)

I mean, does a DVI → VGA adapter suitable for the included HDMI → DVI adapter exist?
How would I find it? Would it work with an old CRT monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it won't work.

The DVI output from a MacBook is DVI-I, containing both analog (DVI-A) and digital (DVI-D) data.

DVI-D is very similar to HDMI bar the audio component (both use TDMS, though the HDMI can use a larger colour space).  So HDMI --> DVI-D is simple - electrically compatible.

DVI-A contains analog data equivalent to VGA - again a trivial conversion.  So DVI-I ---> VGA is simply choosing which pins to pass through.

BUT

HDMI doesn't contain the DVI-A component so plugging the connectors together, though physically feasible, will simply transmit a null signal.

Sorry.

To get this to work as you want would require non-trivial processing (and all the HDCP fuss) to produce an image and then export in analogue.  And would be legally awkward anywhere in US jurisdiction to produce or possess...

Comment: are you talking about mac mini too? And what about that guy that bought a mini-DVI->VGA adapter for macbook?

Comment: Any recent Apple hardware with a DVI port is sending DVI-I, hence has the analog component for the DVI->VGA.  The problem is that the HDMI->DVI only delivers the digital signal.  To put it another way, consider HDMI as (-D), DVI as (AD) and VGA as (A-).  DVI can talk to either as it's "bilingual"; HDMI and VGA don't have any common ground.

Comment: cancelled comment